# vb.net - xmlserializer deserialize omitting first part of text that contains tags

Tags: vb.net, tags, xmlserializer

I have xml that looks like

```
<AddResponse xmlns="http://www.test.com/webservices">
   <ServerName>51</ServerName>
   <Response Type="ERROR">
      <ErrorDesc Type="VALIDATE" Number="215">We are sorry, that number is already in use.  If it is your mobile number, we need to verify it with you.  Please complete the one time verification by submitting your request at <a href="[ContactUs]" target="_blank" class="contact">Contact Us</a> using the keyword MYMOBILE</ErrorDesc>
   </Response>
   <ExternalInfo>
      <![CDATA[?]]>
   </ExternalInfo>
</AddResponse>
```

But when this is deserialized, it is returning just "using the keyword MYMOBILE" as ErrorDesc instead of the whole 
We are sorry, that number is already in use.  If it is your mobile number, we need to verify it with you.  Please complete the one time verification by submitting your request at Contact Us using the keyword MYMOBILE

Can you please let me know why its omitting the first part and how to retain it?
Note: this works fine for rest of xml data that doesn't have html tags in it.

Comment: Not sure what your serializer is picking up but you'll need to escape the XML reserved characters in your error string. Or better yet, wrap it in a `CDATA` section

Comment: CDATA worked. Thanks so much!